# List all available items with Apache Solr if the search keyword is empty

Tags: 7, search

I have created 2 search pages with [Apache Solr module](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) one with content type filter and another for search in taxonomy terms. By default if the keyword string is empty the search pages don't return any results. How can I list all available items with certain content type or with taxonomy term in this case? Thanks

Comment: Are there facets involved?

Comment: no, just a simple search pages for content type nodes search and for searching within taxonomy term.

Comment: Then I don't understand how you are listing terms/content types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Letharion, to answer your question I have found this option in the Advanced options region for the search pages. Here is how to get there:

admin/config/search/apachesolr/search-pages

Create a new search page for Solr search with content type filter or enable one for taxonomy/term/%

Select "Show enabled facets' blocks in their configured regions and first page of all available results" under the Advanced options for this page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check "Custom Filter" text box and add text : bundle:content type, content type is your specific content type name