# Allow blank search/list all items with 1.x apache solr module

Tags: search

When a user enters a blank search, by clicking "search" right away, or entering the search result url directly, the initial version of the [Apache Solr Search Integration](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module, 6.x-1.x series, tells the user to "Please enter some keywords".

I would like it to issue the empty search, thereby returning all available results. This question [List all available items with Apache Solr if the search keyword is empty](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36334/list-all-available-items-with-apache-solr-if-the-search-keyword-is-empty) asks the same for the second generation of the module, 6.x-3.x and 7.x-1.x, but that answer doesn't apply.

I've tried hacking out the `if ($keys == ''` check that yields the "error" message, but that simply results in no results at all.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the below patch that seems to do the trick. The patch looks much larger than it needs to because I corrected the indentation after I removed an `if`.

Anyone that considers using this patch should be aware that this will [hack](https://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core) the module. You should understand what that means, and be using a [make file](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33403/how-to-effectively-manage-a-site-with-drush-make) to avoid future complications.

```
$ diff -u apachesolr_search.module_ apachesolr_search.module
--- apachesolr_search.module_   2013-02-11 10:12:17.814561087 +0100
+++ apachesolr_search.module    2013-02-11 13:29:10.450336901 +0100
@@ -159,24 +159,22 @@ 
   if (isset($_GET['filters'])) {
     $filters = trim($_GET['filters']);
   }  
-  // Only perform search if there is non-whitespace search term or filters:
-  if ($keys || $filters) {
-    // Log the search keys:
-    $log = $keys;
-    if ($filters) {
-      $log .= 'filters='. $filters;
-    }  
-    watchdog('search', '%keys (@type).', array('%keys' => $log, '@type' => t('Search')), WATCHDOG_NOTICE, l(t('results'), 'search/'. $type .'/'. $keys));

-    // Collect the search results:
-    $results = search_data($keys, $type);
+  // Log the search keys:
+  $log = $keys;
+  if ($filters) {
+    $log .= 'filters='. $filters;
+  }
+  watchdog('search', '%keys (@type).', array('%keys' => $log, '@type' => t('Search')), WATCHDOG_NOTICE, l(t('results'), 'search/'. $type .'/'. $keys));

-    if ($results) {
-      $results = theme('box', t('Search results'), $results);
-    }  
-    else {
-      $results = theme('box', t('Your search yielded no results'), variable_get('apachesolr_search_noresults', apachesolr_search_noresults()));
-    }  
+  // Collect the search results:
+  $results = search_data($keys, $type);
+  
+  if ($results) {
+    $results = theme('box', t('Search results'), $results);
+  }  
+  else {
+    $results = theme('box', t('Your search yielded no results'), variable_get('apachesolr_search_noresults', apachesolr_search_noresults()));
   }  
   if (empty($form)) {
     // The form may be altered based on the query that was run.
@@ -998,9 +996,6 @@ 
     $get['retain-filters'] = '1';
   }  
   $form_state['redirect'] = array($base . $keys, $get);
-  if ($keys == '' && !$queryvalues) {
-    form_set_error('keys', t('Please enter some keywords.'));
-  }  
 }
```